# Foreach Iteration Null

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, linq-to-xml

I am using LINQ to filter the XmlNode returned from Sharepoint WSS3's `listService.GetListItems()` method.

This is the XML it returns:
http://pastebin.com/mqHcserY

I observed that the last row is different to the others, it does not contain the following attributes.

```
ows_ContentType
ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu
ows_LinkFilename
ows_BaseName 
ows__EditMenuTableStart
```

So bearing this in mind I filter the results with LINQ:

```
XmlNode items = listService.GetListItems(listName, string.Empty, query, viewFields, string.Empty, queryOptions, g.ToString());

// Namespace for z: prefix
XNamespace xns = "#RowsetSchema";

XElement root;
using (XmlReader xr = new XmlNodeReader(items)) { root = XElement.Load(xr); }

// This query returns XElements that are Folder types
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from child in root.Descendants(xns + "row")
                               where child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value != null && child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value == "Folder"
                               select child;

foreach (XElement xml in result)
{
    //Exception when attempts to loop final XElement
}
```

However when I iterate through the results I get a `NullReferenceException`. In a Foreach loop it will happily iterate through every object until it gets to the last one, then it will throw an exception.

This last object is the one that differs from the other rows (I know this through process of elimination, I saw every other row get looped past) and should have been filtered out of my results as it does not have the "ows_ContentType" attribute.

I changed my LINQ to `where child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value != null && child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value == "Folder"` in attempt to filter anything that would contain a null value but I have the same results.
I have looked at a few [samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Restriction-Operators-b15d29ca#WhereSimple3) and I appear to have the correct syntax.

Could someone please explain what is causing this last XElement to return null?
I really don't understand why it would add a null instance to the `<IEnumerable<XElement> result` collection.

Comment: Are you _modifying_ the nodes at all in your loop?

Comment: how about where child.Attribute("ows_ContentType") != null instead of calling the value? calling value from a not existing node will throw an exception

Comment: Ah, well that makes perfect sense. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the value of a non existing attribute will cause a nullreference because the node simply doesn't exist.

```
child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value
```

throws an exception by calling the value of the missing element.

use this instead:

```
child.Attribute("ows_ContentType") != null
```

implemented:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from child in root.Descendants(xns + "row")
                           where child.Attribute("ows_ContentType") != null && child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value == "Folder"
                           select child;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether the element is null NOT the value of the element.

```
child.Attribute("ows_ContentType") != null && child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value == "Folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that LINQ2XML simply allows you to use `(string)someXElement` and `(string)someXAttribute` which will give null if the XElement or XAttribute is null or the Value of the XElement or XAttribute if it exists. That means you code can be shortened to use

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = from child in root.Descendants(xns + "row")
                               where (string)child.Attribute("ows_ContentType") == "Folder"
                               select child;
```

Answer (score 0):

The last node doesn't contain an "ows_ContentType" attribute, but your where clause is looking for the value of that *missing* attribute.

Possibly you need

```
where child.Attribute("ows_ContentType") != null 
&& child.Attribute("ows_ContentType").Value == "Folder"
```

Comment: _Really_ making sure that `child.Attribute("ows_ContentType")` isn't null :)

Comment: For my own interest, according to this answer the were clause terminates if it has found a condition that results false? Else when it did check for the node being null it would also request the value and check that for being null causing an execption because the node was null?

Comment: @Rawlin: D'oh, how did that get in there?

Comment: @middelpat: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. The where caluse doesn't _terminate_, it will skip items when the condition is false. if `child.Attribute("ows_ContentType") == null` it will not evaluate the second part of the && condition. See "short-circuit" here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @BinaryWorrier your comment just answered my question. Thanks :)